# Sun's HTTP-Server Read Data directly

Tags: java, http, httpserver

I am trying to get the Value of for example a Textfield on the Website...

Is there an other way than reading it from the uri?
For Example something like

```
getContent().getvar("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use library like `jsoup` ([here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup)) to connect to the site (url) and get the data in DOM format. Below is an example code snippet:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println("title : " + title);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

You can use methods like `select` to get the required element, e.g.:

```
Element head= doc.select("div.head").first();
```

[Here](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) is the javadoc of Document class and [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/3-examples-of-parsing-html-file-in-java-using-jsoup.html) are some examples.

If you have HTML code of the website, you can read it with `jsoup` and convert it into `Document` object. Unfortunately, there is no *direct way* to read the content of website/page without actually connecting to it (via uri).